# Foursquare menu pricing information

Tags: php, json, foursquare

I am working on a project where i need to fetch the foursquare menu through API and populate them in our system. I can see that each menu items have 4 tag **entryId, name, description and prices**. Prices value contains multiple prices like the following..

```
{
    prices: [
        "(With Rice, Beans, Cheese, Salsa, Sour Cream & Greens) $5.50"
        "(Add Choice Of Meat Or Veggies) $7.00"
    ]
}
{
    prices: [
        "(Bean & Cheese Only) $2.50"
        "(Add Choice Of Meat Or Veggies) $1.00"
        "(Add Lettuce, Salsa, Sour Cream) $1.00"
        "(Add Guacamole (1 Scoop)) $0.50"
        "(Baby Burro With The Works) $5.00"
    ]
}
```

I didn't find any documentation on foursquare site regarding this prices. Can anyone help me to understand what these values means..

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

These are the price values for the listed variations of the containing dish. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that this is prices for different combinations. But i want to know something more specific. Like 2nd item name is Baby Burro and we can treat "(Bean & Cheese Only) $2.50" and "(Baby Burro With The Works) $5.00" as base price and rest of the 3 options as modifiers (you can add them in during placing order). I guess foursquare follow a standard way to maintain this. So i want to know about their prices specification..

Comment: Ah, I see. This menu data comes from an external partner (SinglePlatform) and I don't think they give us any additional structure around the data that we can pass along. I can double check though.

Comment: Just checked -- we don't receive any special markup. The data was basically collected with the intent for display to a user so it lacks a lot of useful markup that you might want for programatic purposes.